# Differentiation under integration of a function of 3 variable

Tags: integration

Can anyone tell me why 
$\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x \int_c^d f(x,y,z)dz dy=\int_c^d f(x,x,z)dz+\int_a^x \int_c^d f_x(x,y,z)dz dy$ ?

Comment: This seems to be simple product rule.

Comment: @Feyre it is more chain rule, isn't it?

Comment: hint: Try to differentiate $G(x, y) = \int_a^y g(x, u) \;\mathrm d u$ and then use chain rule on $\frac{d}{dx} G(x,x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x,y) = \int_{c}^d f(x,y,z) \textrm{d}z$.
Then we have by [Differentiation under the integral sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{ \partial }{\partial x} \int_a^x g(x,y) \textrm{d}y &=& g(x,x) + \int_a^x \frac{ \partial }{\partial x} g(x,y) \textrm{d}y \\
&=& \int_c^d f(x,x,z) \textrm{d}z + \int_a^x \frac{ \partial }{\partial x} \int_c^d f(x,y,z) \textrm{d}z \textrm{d}y \\
&=&\int_c^d f(x,x,z) \textrm{d}z + \int_a^x \int_c^d \frac{ \partial }{\partial x} f(x,y,z) \textrm{d}z \textrm{d}y 
\end{eqnarray}
We used the Differentiation under the integral sign in the first step on $g(x,y)$ and in the last step on $f(x,y,z)$.